# From woocommerce order to customized pdf

Tags: excel, wordpress

I built a website using Wordpress and WooCommerce. Once i have created an order, 
i need to have a final page(that i will then convert into pdf) to sum up the order in details. For instance, i need a sheet with the name of the company, some information about the guest and a detailed description of the products with pictures. Of course some information will be static and Others will come from the order.

1) I do not need an invoice (there are several plug-ins for that), i would need a final page showing the information with a layout i choose. Is there any drag and drop tool that helps me costumize a page with static(logo, client info) and dynamic(orders) information?

2) At this point, i can export my order details into Excel file. Is there any way to automatically generate a pdf with custom layout from an Excel file?

Comment: With Excel VBA you could easily turn an export into a nicely formatted PDF.  You need to figure out exactly what you want

Comment: Oh that sounds interesting, thanks a lot. Could you please tell me a bit more, or give me a link to follow? As said, i have an Excel file with my order (that can include multiple items) and i need a nice pdf to sum up the Whole thing. thanks a lot